# VerifyError when running Spock-spec with mock/stub from inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spock

This used to work:

From inside Eclipse, select a Spock spec that has a (spock) mock or stub in it and select Run as -> JUnit Test.

Suddenly I can't run these anymore but get a java.lang.VerifyError.

When running specs without any mock/stub it works as expected and when running from a Gradle build this is not happening.

This is the stacktrace I get when running Spec with a stub from inside Eclipse:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final\
   method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;\
   [Ljava/lang/String;)V
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:80)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:47)
at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:282)
at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.StubImpl(SpecInternals.java:131)
at se.hd.taglib.TaglibSpecBase.stubPageContext(TaglibSpecBase.groovy:43)
```

I haven't set any arguments for the run configurations (because I didn't need to before), but is there perhaps some runtime or environment variables that I can set in the Run configuration to fix this problem?

- Spock:  `org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0`
- Groovy: `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.6`
- Eclipse: `Version: Juno Service Release 1 Build id: 20121004-1855`, (running on jdk1.7.0_06.jdk, although the source level set to 1.6)
- Groovy-Eclipse plugin: `2.7.1.xx-RELEASE-20121219-0800-e42`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your Eclipse class path has the wrong CGLIB (or ASM) version. Spock 0.7 was compiled against `cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2`.

Comment: Thanks!! Moving the "*Gradle Dependencies*" entry to the top of the list `"Project Properties" > "Java Build Path" > "Order and Export"` made it possible to run the specs as junit-tests again.